# cannot access my DB server on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

```
server OS: Ubuntu 14.04
MYSQL Server version: 5.5.43-0ubuntu
```

The output of:

```
select User, host from user
```

is:

```
db    %
db    localhost
```

In my /etc/mysql/my.cnf, I made sure that bind-address is set to the real IP address of the server. I can connect to the server from my laptop using sftp and ssh

Yet, it refuses to connect me when I try to connect using mysqlbench error: can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxxxx' 10061

I can also access the web server fine from a browser, it displays the default ubuntu page.

What am I missing?

## Update:

I was able to connect when I did: bind-addess=0.0.0.0

This obviously creates a security risk, as you can connect from any IP address, but there was an issue with the way Amazon EC2 assigns internal and external IP addresses, so I have to figure out the correct IP address to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied and pasted that output from your SELECT statement, you have a typo in 'localhost'. That could be causing your problem.

Comment: No, that was a typo of my own. If I had this wrong, mysql would not allow me in.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Add `bind-address=my_server_ip_address` in my.ini (my.cnf) file after `[mysqld]`

If you have lost the root pwd, there is a workaround using `--skip-grant-tables`.

Comment: I tried that before asking my question. Please see my question. I believe the problem is with the way Amazon assigns the IP Address. When I switched the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 I was able to connect fine. This is of course a security issue, but I will figure that out separately.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully connected to MySQL on Ubuntu 14 when I set the bind-address to the AWS private IP.

Comment: It is less work to use default bind 0.0.0.0, and it does not add much risk, since it is reachable from outside in both cases subject to amazon security zone settings.